# Bootstrap How to add a button to the top-left corner of a jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to place the button inside the jumbotron in the top-left-most corner rather than just above it?

Currently I have:

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
</a>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header text-center">
            <h1>Title of Page</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button creates a noticable bar above the jumbotron (which looks like a rubbish navbar!)

How can I place the button in the top-left-most corner to eliminate this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. Just add absolute positioning to the button and put it INSIDE your jumbotron, not above it.

```
.jumbotron {position:relative;}
#buttonmenu {position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/vmmhsyhYlU

Comment: You're welcome. If this was helpful please mark as answered.

Comment: if you put some content before the jumbotron, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: You should also to add `position: relative` to class `jumbotron` to stop the issue @FelippeDuarte mentions